# Use caching in private context with Symfony 2

Tags: caching, symfony, private

I'm trying to cache a profile user page. For this, I use :

```
$response = new Response();
$response->setETag(md5($response->getContent()));

if ($response->isNotModified($this->getRequest())) {
    return $response;
}
```

But, the application never use the cache because *$this->getRequest()->getEtags()* (which use in *isNotModified* function) is always empty. If I set

```
$response->setPublic()
```

All is ok. So, how can I use caching in Private context ?

Thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using *private* response in Symfony 2, it sets the following header:

```
Cache-Control: private
```

According to the [HTTP 1/1 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1):

> **private**
>
> > Indicates that all or part of the response message is intended for a single user and MUST NOT be cached by a shared cache. This allows an origin server to state that the specified parts of the response are intended for only one user and are not a valid response for requests by other users. A private (non-shared) cache MAY cache the response.

That means that you **CAN'T** use `ETag` header with `Cache-Control: private`.

Comment: Ok, so I will try with Max-Age or other way. Thank !